# How to Change Font in a SQL Server Agent Job Properties Editor in SSMS

Tags: fonts, ssms, edit, sql-agent

SQL Server Management Studio offers what appear to be hundreds of options for using hundreds of fonts.  The one it does not appear to offer is the one I could really use.  I know this because I went to the trouble of changing every single option to the font I like.

When I pull up a job in SQL Agent from SSMS and try to edit a step, it is always displayed in a so-called proportional font (Arial, if I'm not mistaken), and it's always very small. I truly despise these proportional fonts and their Lilliputian size, but I have found no method for changing it.  Does anyone know how to do it?  Thanks.